# FTP login to get file, getting no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

I've been working on retrieving a file from my ftp server, the intention is to get the file, untar it on the local machine and compare the MD5 sum to the locally install package. My main focus is getting this file from the ftp server.

After running the script I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tgzTest.py", line 27, in <module>
    proof = tarfile.is_tarfile("test.tgz")
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2585, in
    is_tarfile t = open(name)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1660, in
    open return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1722, in
    gzopen fileobj = bltn_open(name, mode + "b")
  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.tgz'
```

### The following is the code I'm currently using, thanks for any suggestions!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tarfile
import os
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import hashlib

ftpServer = 'myserver.com'
password = 'null'

os.chdir("/home/user/testFolder")

ftp = FTP(ftpServer)

ftp.login('Anonymous', password)
print "You're in"

fileDir = "/pub/pkgsrc/base_pkgs"
tfile = "test.tgz"

ftp.cwd(fileDir)

print ftp.pwd()

tar = tarfile.open("test.tgz", 'r|gz')

for file in tar.getmembers():
        print file.name
tar.close()
```

Comment: The problem is on line 27 which you haven't  shown us: `proof = tarfile.is_tarfile("test.tgz")`

Comment: Sorry I removed that line, it was erroneous. This is what it originally said: proof = tarfile.is_tarfile("test.tgz")
print proof. This is what it originally said:

Comment: What error are you getting then?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tgzTest.py", line 26, in <module>
    tar = tarfile.open("test.tgz", 'r|gz')
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1689, in open
    _Stream(name, filemode, comptype, fileobj, bufsize),
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 403, in __init__
    fileobj = _LowLevelFile(name, mode)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 376, in __init__
    self.fd = os.open(name, mode, 0666)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.tgz'

Comment: The file doesn't exist on your machine. You need to retrieve it. Have a look at [the example in the ftplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tarfile` package expects files in the local file system, not on the FTP server. You have to download the file first using the `retrbinary()` method of the `ftp` object, and pass the path to the downloaded file to `tarfile.open()`.

Comment: Thanks to Peter and Mike for leading me to the solution, I was able to write to a temp file for further processing of the file.